# When to create new NSURLSession?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

What is the best practices for reusing `NSURLSessions`? From what I can tell, it seems that as long as the configuration (timeouts, caching policies, etc.) does not need to change, there is no need to create a new one (since you can spawn new tasks from it).

So can a single `NSURLSession` be reused for an entire app? Per domain/endpoint? Per request?

Comment: @matt This seems like a perfectly valid question. E.g. are there any cases when an `NSURLSession` becomes invalid? In [Life Cycle of a URL Session](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/NSURLSessionConcepts/NSURLSessionConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i-CH2-SW2) it says "reassociate with the session if your app crashes or is terminated or suspended" - in particular that last point - if my app is suspended, do I need to do anything when it resumes? (That quote is about background sessions, but it's illustrative of the ambiguity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout the docs. Specifically "**Like most networking APIs, the NSURLSession API is highly asynchronous.**"

You can always create a networking class that specifically handles all of your networking for the app. So reusing is not only an option but is also recommended.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/

[Here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/networking-with-nsurlsession-part-1--mobile-21394) is a pretty good tut that explains the differences between NSURLSession and NSULConnection for better understanding of it's intended usage.